# how to get bitrate from master m3u8 file by parsing BANDWIDTH TAG?

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

my master looks like this,

BANDWIDTH=2628000,RESOLUTION=1280x720

my chunklist file looks like this,

EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
EXTINF:6.000,
media_0_0.ts

how to get bitrate for this strem, when using this as a input for transcoding?

somewhere in internet, i saw that bandwidth/chunk duration will give,